# How to run FastAPI / Uvicorn in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to run a "local" web app on Google Colab using FastAPI / Uvicorn like some of the Flask app sample code I've seen but cannot get it to work. Has anyone been able to do this? Appreciate it.

#### Installed FastAPI & Uvicorn successfully

```
!pip install FastAPI -q
!pip install uvicorn -q
```

#### Sample app

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

#### Run attempts

```
#attempt 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("/content/fastapi_002:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

```
#attempt 2
#uvicorn main:app --reload
!uvicorn "/content/fastapi_001.ipynb:app" --reload
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run FastAPI application inside Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070505/how-to-run-fastapi-application-inside-jupyter)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use **ngrok** to export a port as an external url. Basically, ngrok takes something available/hosted on your localhost and exposes it to the internet with a temporary public URL.

First install the dependencies

```
!pip install fastapi nest-asyncio pyngrok uvicorn
```

Create your app

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*'],
)

@app.get('/')
async def root():
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

Then run it down.

```
import nest_asyncio
from pyngrok import ngrok
import uvicorn

ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8000)
print('Public URL:', ngrok_tunnel.public_url)
nest_asyncio.apply()
uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive. Are there any limitations to be aware of when running it like this? Perhaps I should run the server from one notebook and point to a .py file in my gdrive I'm updating as the server main? My use case is ML inference/prediction APIs I've got working locally on my laptop. Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach without having to use ngrok or nest-asyncio:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from uvicorn import Config, Server

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

config = Config(app)
server = Server(config=config)
await server.serve()
```

This won't do any multi-processing or hot-reloading but gets the job done if you just want to quickly run the a simple ASGI app from Jupyter.

This can be achieved using [Hypercorn](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/how_to_guides/api_usage.html) as well.

---

**EDIT**: The above works fine in local Jupyter, but since Colab [still doesn't support top-level `await` statements](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1553) (as of July 2022) you'd need to replace the last line of the snippet above with something like:

```py
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(server.serve())
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what is the url when you run this? The accepted answer has a print statement - can you please share one for this method?

Comment: Uvicorn defaults to serving on 127.0.0.1:8000. See https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/config.py#L212.

Answer (score 0):

Some times we get an error like :

> PyngrokNgrokError: The ngrok process errored on start: authentication failed: Usage of ngrok requires a verified account and authtoken.

- For this first we have to create an auth token and set it to the ngrok we are running
- Head over to [ngrok tunnel](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/tunnels/authtokens)

[image: Ngrok Dashboard]

[image: ngrok tunnel]

- Create an auth tunnel and copy the auth token

> You can also simply get the auth token from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken

- create app

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

    app = FastAPI()

    app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*'],
    )

    @app.get('/')
    async def root():
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

- Now add the token in your code

```
!pip install pyngrok
import nest_asyncio
from pyngrok import ngrok
import uvicorn

# Get your authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken
auth_token = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"

# Set the authtoken
ngrok.set_auth_token(auth_token)

# Connect to ngrok
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8000)

# Print the public URL
print('Public URL:', ngrok_tunnel.public_url)

# Apply nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

# Run the uvicorn server
uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```