# How to make a large file accessible to external APIs?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, web-development-server

I'm new to webdev, and I have this use case where a user sends a large file (e.g., a video file) to the API, and then this file needs to be accessible to other APIs (which could possibly be on different servers) for further processing.

I'm using FastAPI for the backend, defining a file parameter with a type of `UploadFile` to receive and store the files. But what would be the best way to make this file accessible to other APIs? Is there a way I can get a publicly accessible `URL` out of the saved file, which other APIs can use to download the file?

Comment: _Is there a way I can get a publicly accessible URL out of the saved file_ I'm not sure I understand this question.  Your API has the file, so you can serve it up however you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Returning a File Response

First, to return a `file` that is saved on disk from a FastAPI backend, you could use [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse) (in case the file was already fully loaded into memory, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804)). For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

some_file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def main():
    return FileResponse(some_file_path)
```

In case the `file` is too large to fit into memory—as you may not have enough memory to handle the file data, e.g., if you have 16GB of RAM, you can’t load a 100GB file—you could use [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects). That way, you don't have to read it all first in memory, but, instead, load it into memory in chunks, thus processing the data one chunk at a time. Example is given below. If you find `yield from f` being rather slow when using `StreamingResponse`, you could instead create a custom generator, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

some_file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def main():
    def iterfile():
        with open(some_file_path, mode="rb") as f:
            yield from f

    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="video/mp4")
```

### Exposing the API to the public

As for exposing your API to the public—i.e., external APIs, users, developers, etc.—you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (or [expose](https://expose.dev/), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802911/17865804)).

Ngrok is a cross-platform application that enables developers to expose a local *development server* to the Internet with minimal effort. To embed the `ngrok` agent into your FastAPI application, you could use [`pyngrok`](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok)—as suggested [here](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with#fastapi) (see [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#fastapi) for a FastAPI integration example). If you would like to run and expose your FastAPI app through [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) (using `ngrok`), instead of your local machine, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833779/17865804) (plenty of tutorials/examples can also be found on the web).

If you are looking for a more permanent solution, you may want to have a look at cloud platforms—more specifically, a Platform as a Service (PaaS). I would strongly recommend you thoroughly read [FastAPI's Deployment documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/). Have a closer look at [About HTTPS](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/) and [Deployments Concepts](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/concepts/).

### Important Note

By exposing your API to the outside world, you are also exposing it to various forms of attack. Before exposing your API to the public—even if it’s for free—you need to make sure you are offering secure access (use `HTTPS`), as well as `authentication` (verify the identity of a user) and `authorisation` (verify their access rights; in other words, verify what specific routes, files and data a user has access to)—take a look at 1. [OAuth2 and JWT tokens](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/), 2. [OAuth2 scopes](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/), 3. [Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), 4. [Get Current User](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/get-current-user/) and [How to Implement Role based Access Control With FastAPI](https://learnings.desipenguin.com/post/rolechecker-with-fastapi/).

Addtionally,  if you are exposing your API to be used publicly, you may want to limit the usage of the API because of expensive computation, limited resources, [DDoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), [Brute-force attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack), [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), or simply due to monthly cost for a fixed amount of requests. You can do that at the application level using, for instance, [slowapi](https://github.com/laurents/slowapi) (related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183527/17865804)), or at the platform level by setting the rate limit through your hosting service (if permitted). Furthermore, you would need to make sure that the files uploaded by users have the permitted file extension, e.g., `.mp4`, and are not files with, for instance, a `.exe` extension that are potentially harmful to your system. Finally, you would also need to ensure that the uploaded files do not exceed a predefined `MAX_FILE_SIZE` limit (based on your needs and system's resources), so that authenticated users, or an attacker, would be prevented from uploading extremely large files that would result in consuming server resources in a way that the application may end up crashing. You shouldn't rely, though, on the `Content-Length` header being present in the `request` to do that, as this might be easily altered, or even removed, by the client. You should rather use an approach similar to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) (have a look at the "Update" section) that uses `request.stream()` to process the incoming data in chunks as they arrive, instead of loading the entire file into memory first. By using a simple counter, e.g., `total_len += len(chunk)`, you can check if the file size has exceeded the `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, and if so, raise an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception) with `HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE` status code (see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) as well, for more details and code examples).

Read more on FastAPI's [Security documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/) and [API Security](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/security/api/what-is-api-security/) on Cloudflare.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and effort to write such a detailed answer! This is extremely helpful for complete beginners like me who don't even know the right terminology to ask webdev-related questions. I'll study your answer in detail and make use of the resources you've provided. Thanks again! :)