# Split either csv or xlsx file on file upload into mulitple chunked .csv or .xlsx file using javascript to be received by fastapi

Tags: javascript, fastapi, jquery-file-upload, large-file-upload

Due to backend filesize limit of 5.5MB of the API, I need to chunk large files (only .csv, .xls,.xlsx) when uploaded into chunks of <= 5MB and send each chunk by calling file upload api. Each chunk should be send as file with input file extension. That is, if a large csv file is uploaded via input type file, it will splitted into N number of csv files of <= 5MB and then the API will be called N times.

Here is the front-end:

```
<form method="post" action="https://my_url/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="name" id="firmanavn">Customer Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="num-only" id="name" name="cvr" maxlength="8" pattern="\d{8}"
            oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Need 8 digits')"
            oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required>
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file"
            accept=".csv,.xls,.xlsx,text/csv,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel"
            required />
        <input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload File">
    </form>
```

Here is the backend made by FastAPI:

```
@app.post("/upload", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def upload_file(cvr: str = Form(...), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if file.content_type == 'text/csv' or file.content_type == 'application/vnd.ms-excel' or file.content_type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
        try:
            name = cvr + '_'+ datetime.date.today().strftime('%d_%m_%Y') + '_' + file.filename
            f = file.file
            res = email_vask_file_drive.put(name, f)
            return """ <html> <body> File uploaded successfully </body> </html>"""
```

Furthermore, this is what I came to close with respect to front-end chunking which chunks but cannot be processed. Also I don't understand how to call my backend API properly as this code below was taken from the following code snippet (https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-file-upload-service-vanilla-javascript/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Uploader</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>File Upload Service</h2>


    <input type="text" class="num-only" id="name" name="cvr" maxlength="8" pattern="\d{8}"
        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Need 8 digits')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
        required>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file"
        accept=".csv,.xls,.xlsx,text/csv,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel"
        required />
    <button id="upload">Upload</button>
    <small id="status"></small>

    <script>


        const file = document.getElementById('file');
        const upload = document.getElementById('upload');
        const status = document.getElementById('status');

        upload.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // set status to uploading
            status.innerHTML = 'uploading...';

            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.files[0]);


            fileReader.onload = async (event) => {

                const content = event.target.result;
                const CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1000 * 1024;
                const totalChunks = event.target.result.byteLength / CHUNK_SIZE;

                // generate a file name
                const fileName = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6) + file.files[0].name;


                for (let chunk = 0; chunk < totalChunks + 1; chunk++) {
                    let CHUNK = content.slice(chunk * CHUNK_SIZE, (chunk + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE)


                    await fetch('https://pays_email_vask_f_o_utils.deta.dev/upload', {
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'body': CHUNK
                    })
                }
                status.innerHTML = 'Uploaded!!!';
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I know beside the main concern I portrait in the question. There are many other problems which I would be happy to get feedback but **chunking and uploading chunked file with correct format is main problem here**.

**Please help!!!**

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804).

Comment: @Chris, My fast API is a wrapper which calls a third party API that can only upload a single file which size must be <= 5.5 MB
I did see the answer yesterday but i thought it wont be a good idea to chunk large file in server end. For which I want to split a large csv or XLSX file to N smaller csv or XLSX file which will be <=5 MB max and then call the third party API for N times. Please see: https://docs.deta.sh/docs/micros/about/#technical-specifications

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241648/17865804) as well.

Comment: No I need a free drive with atleast 10 GB limit like https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/about/ where I can send data via the platform API

Comment: Google drive is not GDPR compliant hence I don't want to store personal information there. I need not only a secure but also importantly a fully GDPR compliant file hosting platform with API access to upload, rename, download file. I saw pcloud and cloudinary but it seems like they don't have API to combine chunked data in their end as they also have file size limit when uploading