# How to run FastAPI application inside Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fastapi, uvicorn

I am learning FastAPI and I have this example.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

I saved the script as `main.ipynb`

The tutorial says to run this line of code in the command line: `uvicorn main:app --reload`

I am getting this error:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Python Yamed\SaadAPI> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [21304] using WatchFiles
ERROR:    Error loadinimport module "main".INFO:     Stopping reloader process [21304]
```

The reason is because I am using `.ipynb` as opposed to `.py`.

How can i fix this error while using .ipynb.

Thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run FastAPI / Uvicorn in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833593/how-to-run-fastapi-uvicorn-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you attempted to start the server as usual inside Jupyter, for example:

```py
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

you would get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

This is due to Jupyter already running an event loop, and once Uvicorn calls `asyncio.run()` internally, the above error is raised.

As per [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) documentation:

> This function **cannot** be called when another `asyncio` event loop is
> running in the same thread (see [relevant asyncio implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fe44f728afa2dd506c304641f0481d6813d1dbd/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L188), where the error is raised).
>
> [...]
>
> This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the
> end. It should be used as a main entry point for `asyncio` programs, and
> should ideally only be called **once**.

### Solution 1

If you wouldd like to run `uvicorn` from an already running `async` environment, use [`uvicorn.Server.serve()`](https://www.uvicorn.org/#config-and-server-instances) instead (you could add the below to a new code cell in your Jupyter notebook, and then run it):

```py
import asyncio
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = uvicorn.Config(app)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    await server.serve()
```

or, get the current (running) event loop, using [`asyncio.get_running_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop), and then call [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) for creating a task to run inside the event loop for the current thread:

```py
import asyncio
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = uvicorn.Config(app)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(server.serve())
```

### Solution 2

Alternatively, you can use [`nest_asyncio`](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio), which allows nested use of `asyncio.run()` and `loop.run_until_complete()`:

```py
import nest_asyncio
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code is taking a while to run. is it normal? What does the code do?

Comment: It should normally start the server right away. Try restarting the Jupyter kernel and see if it fixes it. I have also updated the answer above with more details and solutions on the issue.

Comment: Thanks it still taking a while ...very strange I have a 16 RAM of memory. Maybe I should just stick to .py

Comment: The URL is running fine now ...I get HTTP response 200 OK.