# How to run a shiny python app on azure databricks notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks, py-shiny

I tried following the steps in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070505/how-to-run-fastapi-application-inside-jupyter) to run a small shiny python app on azure databricks' notebook. Though the solution works well on my local machine, I am unable to get it to work on databricks. Any help?
Kind regards,

Comment: what errors do you get? please provide more details

Comment: @big_cactus, I did not get a solution.